# Android.Views.InflateException on TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, tabbedpage

**Error:**
Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout'

I have added new TabbedPage and then in **AppShell.xaml**

```
<ShellContent Title="About" Route="AboutTabbedPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutTabbedPage}"  />
```

but when I tap on "About" in emulator it **throws error**:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout'
```

The error is thrown on any new TabbedPage.

the content of TabbedPage is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="myapp.Views.AboutTabbedPage"
            Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myapp.ViewModels"
            
            >
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->

    <ContentPage Title="Tab 2">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Green"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5" />
            <BoxView Color="Green" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

styles.xml in android project is as follows:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change TabLayout in ...Android\Resources\layout\Tabber.xml project from
`android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`
To
`com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`
then it started working as expected.